# wikipedia parser

Tags: java, xml-parsing, wikipedia

I want to read wikipedia page through a parser for example JWPL.
I am able to do it, but my problem is:

I want to count the chars between the headings and Sections, and the number of links.

Using JWPL, I could get a list of the sections inside each link from the list, but I am not able to count the chars.

Overall, my aim is to read a wikipedia page, convert its data model to my datamodel and give out another file which contains my data model.

My data model is a file which would contain: section names, numbers "the count of chars between the section and the next link or other section.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

There's a better way to do it, is to use the current available services in wikipedia.You can interact with it using a set of GET requests
Read the metadata page of wikipedia
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Metadata

Also mediawiki explains a bit on this interaction
http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page

Good luck

Comment: First of all, thanks for replying,i did in the same way, i extract the page and i parsed it in JWPL parser, but i couldnot manage to count the chars between the sections and the links ,or to handle the parser.

Comment: can you further explain. what is your input?why couldn't you parse it?